# How to make a discord bot react to PAST private messages?

Tags: python, discord, python-asyncio, discord.py

I made a simple discord.py bot that reacts whenver it is PM'd. However, if someone messages it while my bot is offline, it will not react. How can i make it display all messages received while it was online on startup?

Current code:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import asyncio

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='.')

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
if message.guild is None and message.author != client.user:

    send_this_console=f'{message.author}: \n{message.content}\n'
    print(send_this_console)
await client.process_commands(message)
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to use message history and track the last message sent.
To get when a message was created:

```py
lastMessageTimestamp = message.created_at
```

You'll need to store this in whatever way you want when your bot is offline (for example with [pickle](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html)) and do this:

```py
async for message in user.history(after = lastMessageTimestamp):
  print(message.content)
```

Comment: I tried your solution, but i got an error i expected: `async for message in user.history(after = searchsince):
NameError: name 'user' is not defined`. How do i iterate over all users that messaged me?

Comment: You need to assign a value to the variable `user` first. Maybe loop over a list of users? Bots don't have aa concept of unread messages in the way that users do.